# SQL N To No Releationship Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, relational-division

I have 3 table by this names

Supplier :For store supplier info

| SupplierID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Supplier 1 |
| 2 | Supplier 2 |
| 3 | Supplier 3 |
| 4 | Supplier 4 |

Product : For store product info

| ProductID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Product 1 |
| 2 | Product 2 |
| 3 | Product 3 |
| 4 | Product 4 |
| 5 | Product 5 |

SupplierProduct : For store Product that supplier can supply

| ProductID | SupplierID |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 4 | 4 |

I want to write a query that get a bunch of product ID and return the supplier ID that have all this product ID (N:N Relation) for example get product ID 2,3 and return just supplier ID 1,2

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions Post the code you have so far, your desired outcome as a text table based on your sample data and state any difficulties you are having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is a question of [*Relational Division With Remainder*](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/t-sql-programming-sql-server/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/), with multiple divisors.**

Firstly, to be able to make good solutions for this, you need your input data in tabular form. You can use a table variable or a Table Valued Parameter for this.

There are many solutions. Here is one common one:

- Join the input data to the `SupplierProduct` table. In your case, you only want the `Supplier` data, so do this in a subquery.
- Group it up and check that the count matches the total count of inputs

```sql
DECLARE @ProductInput TABLE (ProductID int);
INSERT @ProductInput (ProductID) VALUES (2),(3);

SELECT *
FROM Supplier s
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM SupplierProduct sp
    JOIN @ProductInput pi ON pi.ProductID = sp.ProductID
    WHERE sp.SupplierID = s.SupplierID
) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @ProductInput)
;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=133cf4579681f0b73e4082b0b3d32a89)

Another common solution is a double `NOT EXISTS`. This verifies that there are *no* inputs which *do not* have a match. It is generally considered to be less efficient.

```sql
DECLARE @ProductInput TABLE (ProductID int);
INSERT @ProductInput (ProductID) VALUES (2),(3);

SELECT *
FROM Supplier s
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM @ProductInput pi
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
        FROM SupplierProduct sp
        WHERE pi.ProductID = sp.ProductID
          AND sp.SupplierID = s.SupplierID
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `intersect` as follows:

```
select distinct SupplierID 
from SupplierProduct
where ProductID = 2
intersect
select SupplierID 
from SupplierProduct
where ProductID = 3
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5290f432e4ca1d90617ae4346be20ca6)

Comment: Yes but i do'nt know have manay product ID i have so i most use  IN.

Comment: In my Answer, your Product ID List are in the @ProductSelection Table. By leaving uncommented one of the ANDs in the WHERE clause, you can choose one of the 3 sets of ProductsID i put there as examples. Did you checked my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE     @Supplier TABLE (SupplierID int, Name varchar(50));
INSERT INTO @Supplier VALUES
        (1, 'Supplier 1')
    ,   (2, 'Supplier 2')
    ,   (3, 'Supplier 3')
    ,   (4, 'Supplier 4')
;
DECLARE     @Product TABLE (ProductID int, Name varchar(50));
INSERT INTO @Product VALUES
        (1, 'Product 1')
    ,   (2, 'Product 2')
    ,   (3, 'Product 3')
    ,   (4, 'Product 4')
    ,   (5, 'Product 5')
;

DECLARE     @SupplierProduct TABLE (ProductID int, SupplierID int);
INSERT INTO @SupplierProduct VALUES
        (2, 1)
    ,   (3, 1)
    ,   (4, 1)
    ,   (2, 2)
    ,   (3, 2)
    ,   (4, 2)
    ,   (3, 3)
    ,   (4, 3)
    ,   (1, 4)
    ,   (2, 4)
    ,   (4, 4)
;

DECLARE     @ProductSelection   TABLE   (ProductID int)
INSERT INTO @ProductSelection
    SELECT
        ProductID
    FROM @Product
    WHERE   1=1
        --  AND ProductID IN (2, 3) --   returns Suppliers 1, 2
        --  AND ProductID IN (3, 4) --   returns Suppliers 1, 2, 3
            AND ProductID IN (2, 4) --   returns Suppliers 1, 2, 4
;

WITH SupplierList AS
    (
        SELECT
                RowNo = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SP.SupplierID ORDER BY SP.SupplierID)
            ,   S.SupplierID
        FROM    @SupplierProduct    SP
        JOIN    @ProductSelection   P   ON  P.ProductID     = SP.ProductID
        JOIN    @Supplier           S   ON  S.SupplierID    = SP.SupplierID
    )

SELECT  
        SupplierID
FROM    SupplierList
WHERE   RowNo   = (SELECT SUM(1) FROM @ProductSelection)
```